# Why do I get different results when running a program with ld-linux.so and when changing the interpreter with patchelf?

Tags: segmentation-fault, elf, patchelf

What's the difference between running a program with ld + --library-path
and with changing the loader with patchelf?

To illustrate, here is a binary that wouldn't run as is, presumably because of lack of recent versions of libraries:

```
$ ~/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick
/tmp/.mount_magickXiWzgy/usr/bin/magick: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/.mount_magickXiWzgy/usr/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.10)
/tmp/.mount_magickXiWzgy/usr/bin/magick: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /tmp/.mount_magickXiWzgy/usr/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.10)
/tmp/.mount_magickXiWzgy/usr/bin/magick: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/.mount_magickXiWzgy/usr/lib/liblcms2.so.2)
...
$
```

I tried to run it with 3 other loaders and library paths, (core18, core20 and core22). Got ELF file ABI version invalid each time.

```
$ /snap/core18/current/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /snap/core18/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  ~/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick
/home/ychaouche/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick: error while loading shared libraries: /home/ychaouche/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick: ELF file ABI version invalid
$ /snap/core20/current/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /snap/core20/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  ~/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick
/home/ychaouche/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick: error while loading shared libraries: /home/ychaouche/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick: ELF file ABI version invalid
$ /snap/core22/current/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /snap/core22/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  ~/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick
/home/ychaouche/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick: error while loading shared libraries: /home/ychaouche/DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick: ELF file ABI version invalid
$
```

Then got a Segmentation fault when I tried to run it after changing the loader and the rpath directly in the binary with patchelf,
like so:

```
$ patchelf --set-interpreter /snap/core18/current/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --set-rpath /snap/core18/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  magick
$ ./magick
Segmentation fault
$ ldd magick
        not a dynamic executable
$
```

even ldd fails to recognize it as a dynamic executable, although readelf can read it.

here's output of ldd as requested by @user10489

```
$ file DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick
DOWNLOADS/APPS/magick: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9fdbc145689e0fb79cb7291203431012ae8e1911, stripped
$
```

My question is why do I have ELF file ABI version invalid when specifying the loader from the command line, and a segmentation fault when changing the loader (and rpath) inside the binary?

Answer (score 2):

The entire point of library versioning is to prevent issues when the ABI of the library changes and allow the application to find the libraries that match the ABI it expects.

By forcing the library version, you have forced the executable to try to call functions whose ABI is different than what it expects.  The results at best will fail with errors, and at worst will crash in unpredictable ways.

If you want to use the program with a specific library, you will need to either find a version compiled for that library, or recompile it from source code, assuming the API can match.

Comment: patchelf allows you to change where the libraries should be fetched w/o the need to recompile. See msb's answere here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/44710599#44710599

Comment: You have completely ignored my point.  Yes, you can force it to use another library.  No it won't work well if the ABI has changed.  The patchelf method only works if you are changing only the *path* to the same version of the library.  If it is a different major version, this just isn't going to work.  Patchelf isn't magic that lets you adapt to a different ABI.  If it works at all, then you got lucky and the parts you tested may have accidentally not had ABI changes.

Comment: The answer you linked even specifies you need to use the same version of the library.

Comment: Thanks @user10489 for the clarification. I totally get your point. This is exactly what I want to achieve. I would like to find the library with the right ABI version and point it to there. What would be the best way to get the needed ABI version and the target ABI version?

Comment: The best way is to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to tell it where to find it and let it pick its own library instead of forcing it.  You can use `ldd` on most binaries to see what it needs and if it found everything.  There's also a library path (LD_RUN_PATH if you were linking it) hardcoded in the binary and that can probably be adjusted with patchelf too.

Comment: For the dynamic linker itself, you can use the `file` command on all binaries to determine that.

Comment: Thanks. ldd did not help in my case. You can read the question again and find the trace to ldd execution.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned `file`.  You should include the output from both of those in your question.

Comment: ok updated question with requested execution trace.